# Unable to use objection with corellium device

Tags: ios, frida

I am trying to use objection with my Corellium iOS device but I am getting the following error.

```
Using USB device `iPhone`
Unable to connect to the frida server: unable to communicate with remote frida-server; please ensure that major versions match and that the remote Frida has the feature you are trying to use
```

Corellium iOS Device Details: (iPhone 7 Plus | 14.3 | Jailbroken)

iOS Device Frida Version: 16.0.1

MacOS Frida Version: 16.0.1

For connecting to my virtual device I am using Tunnelblick and USBFlux. The connection is successful because I can SSH to my device and use frida-ps and frida-ls-devices without any issues.

However, when I issue the objection command, I encounter an error.

```
ubaidahmed@Ubaids-MacBook-Pro ~ % frida-ps -Ua
PID  Name     Identifier                       
3  -------  ---------------------------------
593  Cydia    com.saurik.Cydia                 
546  DVIA-v2  com.highaltitudehacks.DVIAswiftv2
ubaidahmed@Ubaids-MacBook-Pro ~ % objection -g 546 explore
Using USB device `iPhone`
Unable to connect to the frida server: unable to communicate with remote frida-server; please ensure that major versions match and that the remote Frida has the feature you are trying to use
```

I even tried to upgrade the frida version to the latest 16.0.8 on my virtual iOS device but again faced the following error in cydia.

Steps followed for updating frida version:

1. Go to Sources
2. Edit > Add > https://build.frida.re - Add Source
3. Select the added entry - build.frida.re > All Packages
4. Select Frida (it shows latest Frida version) and click on Install
5. Installation fails

[image]

Edited: Also, I have tried to use objection with network option but still no success.

[image]

[image]

I have tried to provide as much information as possible related to the issue. Please help me out in resolving this strange issue.

Answer (score 0):

If the connection via virtual USB doesn't work you can switch to a direct TCP connection. Execute `frida -H IP:port` and e.g. use port forwarding to get the frida server port to your local system.

The default frida-server port is `27042`.

#### frida_16.0.8 in Cydia

The recent versions of the Debian package of frida-server don't work (see this [issue](https://github.com/frida/frida/issues/2356)). Keep your existing version or if you need to install it manually download the deb package of frida_16.0.7_iphoneos-arm.deb (do not use the 16.0.8 version, it is defect use at least 16.0.7 or older) from [frida release page](https://github.com/frida/frida/releases/tag/16.0.7).

Download the deb package and install it manually by executing `dpkg -i <frida...iphoneos-arm.deb>`.

Comment: I am using frida 16.0.1 and I have edited the original que with the details about using network option for objection but no success.

Comment: @user3368855 And you are sure frida-server is running on the phone?

Comment: Yes, the frida-server is running. To confirm I did ssh to my virtual iphone and ran: ps aux | grep frida

Comment: Corellium provides built-in frida support: https://support.corellium.com/features/frida so may be you have two versions collide? If i doesn't work as described in the help I would contact support.